# singular value of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix, and $\sigma_k(A)$ the $k$th singular value of $A$.

Show that we have :

$$\sigma_k(A^t A)=(\sigma_k(A))^2$$

Comment: How are the singular values sorted ?

Comment: @P.Quinton: this doesn't really matter, does it ?

Answer (score 0):

$(\sigma_k(A^tA))^2=\lambda_k((A^tA)^t(A^tA))=\lambda_k((A^tA)^2)=(\lambda_k(A^tA))^2=((\sigma_k(A))^2)^2$

Thus $\sigma_k(A^tA)=(\sigma_k(A))^2$

Where $\lambda_k$ is the $kth$ eigenvalue of the matrix .

And here we used the fact that if $M$ is a square matrix then $\lambda(M^n)=\lambda(M)^n$

Answer (score 0):

$$A^TA=(U\Sigma V^T)^TU\Sigma V^T=V\Sigma U^TU\Sigma V^T=V\Sigma U^{-1}U\Sigma V^T=V\Sigma^2V^T$$

gives an SVD of $A^TA$.

At the same time, we see that $\Sigma^2$ is the diagonal matrix of the Eigenvalue decomposition, i.e. $\sigma_{A,k}^2=\lambda_{A^TA,k}$.